# Access Sonarqube on windows 2019 server from outside/internet

Tags: sonarqube, windows-server-2019

I have setup a SonarQube on a hosted virtual Windows 2019 server. it runs via a task scheduler script and is always up.
We created a dns record sonarqube.domainname.com:8080 like we have done many times before for different products, such as Jenkins.
The hosting firm have opened for port 8080 but I still cannot connect to the SonarQube.

Hosting firm writes:

---

the firewall allows and forwards port 8080 to the server- however, it only seems to listen to port 8080 on localhost / loopback - and thus it cannot respond to traffic out of the server.

I think the java program should be configured to listen on the machine IP or on all IPs.

---

I am a software developer not a network specialist and to be honest, I don´t understand what they write.

In sonar.properties

```
# Binding IP address. For servers with more than one IP address, this property specifies which
# address will be used for listening on the specified ports.
# By default, ports will be used on all IP addresses associated with the server.
# sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0
# sonar.web.host=127.0.0.1

# Web context. When set, it must start with forward slash (for example /sonarqube).
# The default value is root context (empty value).
#sonar.web.context=
# TCP port for incoming HTTP connections. Default value is 9000.
#sonar.web.port=9000
sonar.web.port=8080
```

if I try to change host

```
sonar.web.host=
```

to anything but 172.0.0.1 SonarQube does not run.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and now it works. So simple.

```
sonar.web.host=0.0.0.0 // listens on all IP´s for the machince
sonar.web.port=8080
```